# Performance issue in SSE SIMD code

Tags: c, performance, x86, sse

I have a code to rotate a vector around another vector to a given angle. I use quaternions and this [fast formula](http://blog.molecular-matters.com/2013/05/24/a-faster-quaternion-vector-multiplication/) to do this. I wrote two variants, with and without use of SIMD compiler intrinsics.

Variant 1:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <pmmintrin.h>
#include "test2.h"

static __v4sf cross_product_ (__v4sf a, __v4sf b)
{
    __v4sf r1 = a * _mm_shuffle_ps (b, b, _MM_SHUFFLE (1, 3, 2, 0));
    __v4sf r2 = b * _mm_shuffle_ps (a, a, _MM_SHUFFLE (1, 3, 2, 0));
    __v4sf r = r1 - r2;
    return _mm_shuffle_ps (r, r, _MM_SHUFFLE (1, 3, 2, 0));
}

static __v4sf rotate_vector_ (__v4sf base, __v4sf vect)
{
    __v4sf base_re = _mm_shuffle_ps (base, base, 0);
    __v4sf tmp = cross_product_ (base, vect);
    tmp = tmp * _mm_set_ps1 (2.0);

    __v4sf res = vect + base_re*tmp + cross_product_ (base, tmp);
    return res;
}

void rotate_vector (float base[], float vect[], float res[])
{
    __v4sf v = _mm_slli_si128 (_mm_load_ps (vect), 4);
    __v4sf r = rotate_vector_ (_mm_load_ps (base), v);
    r = _mm_srli_si128 (r, 4);
    _mm_store_ps (res, r);
}
```

Variant 2:

```
#include "test2.h"

static void cross_product (const float v1[], const float v2[], float res[])
{
    res[0] =  v1[1]*v2[2] - v1[2]*v2[1];
    res[1] = -v1[0]*v2[2] + v1[2]*v2[0];
    res[2] =  v1[0]*v2[1] - v1[1]*v2[0];
}

void rotate_vector (float base[], float vector[], float res[])
{
    float tmp[3], tmp2[3];
    int i;
    cross_product (base+1, vector, tmp);
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) tmp[i] *= 2.0;
    cross_product (base+1, tmp, tmp2);
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) res[i] = vector[i] + base[0]*tmp[i] + tmp2[i];
}
```

Data layout for quaternion:

```
0......32......64......96......128 bits
 1(real)    i       j       k
```

and for vector:

```
0......32......64......96......128 bits
    x       y       z      XXX
```

Then I try to rotate a preinitialized array of vectors with one rotation quaternion (rotation around axis x to 90 degrees). Uses a lot of RAM!

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "test2.h"

double gettime ()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
    return (double)tv.tv_sec + (0.000001 * (double)tv.tv_usec);
}

#define N 400000000

int main ()
{
    float z = sqrtf(2)/2;
    float a[4] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = {z,z,0,0};
    float (*b)[4] = aligned_alloc (16, 4*N*sizeof(float));
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        bzero (b[i], 16);
        b[i][i%3] = 4;
        b[i][0] = 1;
    }

    double time = gettime();
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
#if 0
        b[i][0] = 1;
#endif
        rotate_vector (a,b[i],b[i]);
    }
    time = gettime() - time;
    printf ("%f %f %f\n", b[0][0], b[0][1], b[0][2]);
    printf ("%f\n", time);
    return 0;
}
```

SIMD variant is about 10% faster than non-SIMD when compiled with clang 3.4 `-O3 -msse3` and executed on AMD FX-6300 processor. But if I remove `#if/#endif`, in other words, write something to a vector which must be rotated on each iteration, SIMD variant slows down a lot and executes about 2-2.5 slower than non-SIMD. So how a single write slows down the whole thing? Is it something to do with cache? I am using FreeBSD 10.2 and trying to test this code with pmcstat(8), but get nothing unusual (e.g. high cache miss rate or something like that).

It seems though, that performance is not affected on Atom processors (tested on Asus Zenfone 2 ze551ml smartphone and Acer Aspire One Happy 2 netbook). So maybe this is processor-specific issue? Or I understand SIMD incorrectly and this is not the right place to apply them?

If you want to compile this example on your machine, here is missing test2.h (you will need ~6Gb of RAM):

```
#ifndef TEST2_H
#define TEST2_H

void quat_mul (float a[], float b[], float c[]);
void rotate_vector (float base[], float vect[], float res[]);

#endif
```

Comment: This would probably be a better question with a more minimal example.  (e.g. simplify the SIMD code as long as it still demonstrates the issue you're seeing, even if it's no longer a meaningful calculation.)  Also, you could have saved a ton of memory by having a repeat loop outside the array loop, so you'd only need an array big enough to exceed cache size (if you want to test for main memory bottlenecks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a single element right before doing a vector load will cause a store-forwarding stall.  That may be what's hurting the perf of your SIMD version.  You could check that with a profiling tool that can record perf counters.  See [Agner Fog's guides](http://agner.org/optimize/), and other links from the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Oh, I just noticed you said perf on Atom is unaffected.  That's strong evidence in support of my theory: Atom has amazing store-forwarding capabilities, and can forward data from a narrow store to a wide load that follows it.  On all other x86 microarchitectures, this causes a store-forwarding stall and has much higher latency.  Agner Fog's microarch pdf explains this.

---

If you want to modify a single vector element, it's probably best to do it with `_mm_insert_ps`.  If you want to modify many, it's prob. best to use `_mm_set_ps` to make a new vector, then `_mm_blend_ps` to combine with the old vector.  `_mm_shuffle_ps` and `_mm_unpacklo_ps`/`_mm_unpackhi_ps` (or `pd`) can also combine data between vectors.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer.

I replaced by-element assignment to an array of floats with creation of a new vector with _mm_set_ps(), rotating and storing the result. Slowdown then disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

You have enough data (6.4 GB) that caches don't matter at all.

On every iteration, you modify one vector element in memory, load the vector with load_ps, do some calculations, write it back. So there's a non-vector write followed by a vector write. The first write will force a cache line to be loaded, then it's partially dirtied, then it is read as a vector and written as a vector. This is all complicated and depending on the precise design of the processor and memory system could lead to a slowdown.

If b [i] [0] were actually used, I would most likely move the assignment b [i] [0] = 1 into the function that you call. So in the vector version, you load_ps the vector b [i], then modify the first element of the vector *in a vector register*, avoiding the interfering with memory.

Comment: It's not that the cache line is dirty.  If you wrote to a part of the cache line that didn't overlap the vector load, there wouldn't be a problem.  Or if you did a 16B store to the address you're about to load, store-forwarding would work (IIRC, all SSE-supporting CPUs can forward an aligned 16B store to a 16B load from the same address).  The only part of your 2nd paragraph that makes sense is that "it's complicated" :P  (And that it's the store that brings the line into L1, but that's not the problem.)